# What's the simplest solution to make four equally sized boxes that is displayed horizontally and centered in a screen responsively?

Tags: css, responsive-design

What's the simplest solution to make four equally sized boxes that is displayed inline (horizontally) and is centered in the screen all through out responsively?

I have four divs with same sizes, displayed inline and is always placed in center, meaning they always have an equal margins on left and write of the screen. And i want it to be responsive. I already tried flex-box but i'm having trouble with browser compatibility with css3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the absolute "best" way. But something like this would definitely work.

```
div {
   width: 22%; //adjust as necessary
   margin-right: 4%; //adjust as necessary
   float: left;
   height: 5em; //adjust or remove as necessary 
}

div.last { //alternatively you could consider using the :last-child selector
   margin-right: 0;
   float: right;
}
```

You will have to apply a class of "last" to the last `div`. Alternatively you could use `div:last-child` if they were all contained in a parent element.

Also, when adjusting the margin/width make sure they  stay relative. `width`x4 + `margin-right`x3 should always = 100 (assuming no padding or borders).